# How to load ajax Bootstrap tabs dinamically with template jinja Flask?

Tags: ajax, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to load data from database to create a menu, how can I pass the data to a Ajax request, need a Ajax Request? When I click in the menu, will load just the link that was click in the tab-pane, not all 3, I didn't find anything about this specific subject:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>HOME</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu 1</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
```

Example with php:

[Dynamic Bootstrap Tabs using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128653/dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-using-php-mysql)

http://www.99logic.com/how-to-create-dynamic-tab-using-ajax-jquery-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty much in the same way as the PHP links you referenced, since it is a mostly client-side solution.

The base page that loads in the browser needs to have the overall tab structure. In this page you'll have to handle click events to the tabs. On each of the tab's click handler you will issue an ajax call to retrieve the corresponding HTML from the server. The URLs for these endpoints could be, for example, `/menu1`, `/menu2`, and so on. The Flask server defines these endpoints and returns the content of each tab in them. You can have these defined as Jinja2 templates if you like. The Ajax request in the client will have a completion callback, and in there you will take the HTML that came from the request and insert it in the tab's body. For everything except the server-side endpoints you can take the code from the PHP solutions, that should all work the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have an example of how will be the Python code?  How I treat the data? It's a JSON? How I turn in JSON? I will have one HTML and a hundred of contents, that will change.

Comment: The Python side will be a normal request that will return a rendered template with the HTML contents of the tab. I would not use JSON for this, just return HTML. The JS side can take the HTML content and attach it directly to the tab.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late answer.